# How to interleave columns from two files?

Tags: join, text, awk, merge

Let's say we have two files (same sized m*n matrices), with columns:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, ..., An
```

and

```
B1, B2, B3, B4, ..., Bn
```

The expected output would be:

```
A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3, A4, B4, ..., An, Bn
```

How can this be done? I guess that there are some awk one-liners, but I haven't been able to build the right one...

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this seems ok in my tests, considering that both files have the same number of lines and fields = same array dimensions:

```
$ cat file1
a1,a2,a3
a4,a5,a6

$ cat file2
b1,b2,b3
b4,b5,b6

$ awk 'NR==FNR{f1[FNR]=$0;next};{split(f1[FNR],ff1,",");split($0,ff2,","); \
for (f=1;f<=length(ff1);f++) printf ff1[f]","ff2[f](f!=length(ff1)?",":"\n")}' file1 file2
a1,b1,a2,b2,a3,b3
a4,b4,a5,b5,a6,b6
```

Quick explanation:
awk reads first the one file and then the second file.
`NR==FNR{f1[FNR]=$0;next}` : read the first file and create an array f1 with indeces the line number of file1 and contents the whole line $0

When the first file is finished then the rest of the code is executed during processing of file2:

`split(f1[FNR],ff1,",")` : Since both files have the same amount of lines, this ones splits previous read records from file1 (stored in array f1) into a new array ff1 by using comma as split delimiter.

`split($0,ff2,",")` : Similarily, this splits $0 = current record / current line of file2 into an array with name ff2, using comma as delimiter.

`for (f=1;f<=length(ff1);f++) printf ff1[f]","ff2[f](f!=length(ff1)?",":"\n")`
This one iterates through the array elements of ff1 (ff1 has the same length of ff2) and prints data from both ff1 and ff2.

`(f!=length(ff1)?",":"\n")` : This prints comma `,` while we have not reached the end of array ff1/ff2 , otherwise prints a newline character `\n`

Comment: Both this and Ed Morton's answers work properly (as indicated in the question, the files are m*n matrices, not just one row). Marked this answer as correct because of the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=", " }
    NR==FNR { a[NR]=$0; next }
    {
        split(a[FNR],f)
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s%s%s", f[i], OFS, $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
' a.txt b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as your input suggests, you're only using a single line of each input, then processing by record might be easier than processing by field. You can read one file through stdin, and read the other file explicitly.

As a one liner, this might look like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=RS=","} {print $1; getline < "f2"; print $1}' f1; echo
```

Broken out for easier reading with comments:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { ORS=RS="," }     # record separator is a comma!
  {
    print $1               # print a trimmed (1-field) record from the first file,
    getline < "file2"      # then get the next record from the second file.
    print $1               # print a record from the second file.
  }
' file1
echo                       # print a newline, since awk didn't.
```

If you'd prefer your output to have spaces after the comma you  could replace the code in the `BEGIN` block with:

```
  BEGIN {RS=","; ORS=", "}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tr` and `rs` (*[reshape a data array](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rs)*), if available. If not, talk to your local admin or hack the planet. First, test data:

```
$ cat foo bar
a1,a2,a3
b1,b2,b3
```

send that to `tr` replacing `,` with space:

```
$ cat foo bar | tr , ' '
a1 a2 a3
b1 b2 b3
```

and on to `rs` for transposing:

```
$ cat foo bar | tr , ' ' | rs -T
a1  b1
a2  b2
a3  b3
```

and finally to another `rs` to squeeze previous on one line:

```
$ cat foo bar | tr , ' ' | rs -T | rs 1
a1  b1  a2  b2  a3  b3
```

Last `rs` could be replaced with `tr \n' ' '`. `rs` honors delimiters for inputing and outputing, see the man page for that. I left the commas out intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

***paste*** + ***tr*** + ***sed*** trick for Unix shell:

`file1` contents:

```
A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7
```

---

`file2` contents:

```
B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7
```

---

```
paste <(tr ',' '\n' <file1) <(tr ',' '\n' <file2) | paste -s | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/, /g'
```

The output:

```
A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3, A4, B4, A5, B5, A6, B6, A7, B7
```

Comment: Important to point out that this solution depends on `bash` for process substitution. The OP hasn't indicated what shell or OS they're using.

Comment: @ghoti, added *for Unix shell*

Comment: Process substitution is not a part of ash, dash, csh, tcsh. I believe bash's notation is shared by AT&T ksh (but I think not pdksh), but this non-POSIX feature works differently in zsh and I don't know if it's supported in fish. So what does "*for Unix shell*" mean?

Answer (score 0):

One more solution using `awk` and `paste` wouldn't hurt.

```
paste -d',' file1 file2 | awk -F ',' '{ 
    z = ""
    for (i=1; i <= NF/2; ++i){ 
        x = i+(NF/2)
        y = $i","$x
        z = z","y
    }
    print substr(z,2,length(z))
}'
```

First, `paste -d',' file1 file2` both files under the same row indices, merging them using the same field-separator = `,`.

Then, in `awk`, `-F ','` takes the commas as field-separator and loops through 1/2 the column indices `i <= NF/2`, finding the corresponding column to interleave `x = i+(NF/2)` and creating a new comma-separated string with both values `y = $i","$x`. Finally, these new strings are concatenated into an empty string `z = z","y` and printed after the loop excluding the first comma `print substr(z,2,length(z))`.

Personally, I found this a bit more explicit than some of the previous solutions using `awk`.